# How to join a CSV list to a table column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
    `id` INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `code` VARCHAR(50),
    `new_table_id` INT(10)
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

And I have a CSV list of code values like so:

```
'23000005619',
'23000019479',
'23000019759',
'23000030169',
'23000032629'
```

I want to join this list with `my_table`.`code` column such that I can find the value to `my_table`.`new_table_id` so I can join that to another table.

My initial thoughts are something along the lines of this (but obviously not syntactically correct):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table mt,
(
  SELECT
    '23000005619',
    '23000019479',
    '23000019759',
    '23000030169',
    '23000032629'
) as ml
WHERE mt.`code` = m1.xx
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**

I would like to avoid temp tables where possible

Comment: Insert your comma separated values into a temp table and then join

Comment: Thanks Pavanred. I would like to avoid temp tables where possible.

Comment: i am curious, how are you planning to get the values from the csv? Hard code or...

Comment: @cctan, I'm given a CSV from a different department. For every code in the list, i need to retrieve extra info. So to answer your question, yes, it will be hard-coded.

Comment: I feel hard code is the way to go: either put it in sql scripts (yours is ok) or in an actual table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I made life harder for myself - this is all that I needed:

```
SELECT mt.code, mt.new_table_id
FROM my_table mt
WHERE mt.code IN
(
  '23000005619',
  '23000019479',
  '23000019759',
  '23000030169',
  '23000032629'
)
```

I might have thrown people off by saying i wanted a join when in fact no join was required.